# Latest gvim unreadable on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Anyone else have issues?

Tags: gvim

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, gvim no longer is readable.  Both the default version that Ubuntu installs (version 8.2.4919) and the lastest released version of gvim (version 9.0.1677)

It comes up with a black background, no readable menus a splattering of stuff in the middle of the window and some icons at the top.

Now I'm running Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM.  But this use to work just fine.

Advice ??

[image: gvim on my Ubuntu installation]

Comment: "Advice ??" Yes, open an issue in Vim's issue tracker, ideally with a minimal reproducible example based on `$ gvim --clean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Ubuntu display server from wayland to Xorg will solve your problem.
https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

Comment: Please [edit] to be more specific: how should the OP make the change? Why would it solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much.  This solved my problem.

Comment: @CharlieJohnson if this answer solved your problem, please accept it with the V shaped button to its left. Thank you.